# Numpy: Array of `arange`s

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to take...

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 8, 10, 15, 50]).reshape((-1, 1)); ncols = 5
```

...and turn it into...

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54]])
```

I was able to do it with `np.apply_along_axis`...

```
>>> def myFunc(a, ncols):
        return np.arange(a, (a+ncols))

>>> np.apply_along_axis(myFunc, axis=1, arr=x)
```

and with `for` loops...

```
>>> X = np.zeros((x.size,ncols))
>>> for a,b in izip(xrange(x.size),x):
        X[a] = myFunc(b, ncols)
```

but they are too slow. Is there a faster way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be able to answer, we really need a more detailed explanation of what exactly you're trying to do. Or perhaps a complete code example that works but is too slow.

Comment: @JanneKarila: Yes, generic is what i'm going for. This is just a simple example. In real life, the values in `x` and the number of columns could be anything. But given values in `x` and `ncol`, return array of `arange`s of shape (`x.size`,`ncol`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
In [9]: x = np.array([0, 8, 10, 15, 50]).reshape((-1, 1))

In [10]: ncols = 5

In [11]: x + np.arange(ncols)
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54]])
```

It adds a row vector to a column vector and relies on [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to do the rest.

This should be as fast as anything: producing a 1000x1000 matrix takes ~1.6ms:

```
In [17]: %timeit np.arange(1000).reshape((-1, 1)) + np.arange(1000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop
```

Comment: Geez...Thanks, @NPE. One of these days, i'll get the hang of this.